# Twiiter Bootstrap carousel making dynamic with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to make a carousel that uses Twitter Bootstrap default JavaScript and CSS but the images should be fetched from the MySQL database.

The HTML for the carousel that i am trying to make dynamic with php is like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="active item">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginLast">
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
   <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

The end result for PHP file that i'm expecting is like this

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <?php renderAds(); ?>
</div>
```

The PHP function that i wrote is like this :

```
function renderAds(){
    $query = queryAds();
    $query_exe = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query_exe) == 0){
        echo '<img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" >';
    }else{

        $numb =1;
        $flag =1;
        while($fetched_data = mysql_fetch_array($query_exe)){

            if($numb == 1){
                if($flag == 1){
                    echo '<div class="active item">';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="item">';
                }
            }elseif($numb == 4){
                echo '<a href="'.$fetched_data['url'].'"  class="pull-left marginLast" ><img src="'.$fetched_data['image_url'].'"></a>';
                echo '</div>';
                $numb =0;
            }else{
                echo '<a href="'.$fetched_data['url'].'" class="pull-left marginTop" ><img src="'.$fetched_data['image_url'].'"></a>';
            }
            $numb++;
            $flag++;
        }


        echo '<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>';
        echo '<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>';
    }


}
```

Here, by differing from default carousel of twitter bootstrap, i made each slide with 4 images, i expect that  each slide transition contains 4 images instead of as by default the single image for one slide. In HTML it works but when I replace it with my PHP function first slide works but if i press next arrow in carousel whole div collapses.

How can I make it work ?

> Note : Here Last image must contain the class marginLast, and the
>   other should have marginTop and pull-left classes.

What I expect to be rendered in html is like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="active item">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginLast">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginLast">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginTop">
                <img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" class="pull-left marginLast">
            </div>

            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
   </div>
```

How can i make my PHP function to display result markup like above?

Edit : The Output i get is like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <!-- Carousel items -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="active item">
                    <a href="xx2" class="pull-left marginTop" ><img src="images/sampleAd.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="xx" class="pull-left marginTop" ><img src="images/sampleAd.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="sample.com"  class="pull-left marginLast" ><img src="images/sampleAd.jpg"></a>
                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>             
          </div><!-- end carousel-inner -->

  </div><!-- myCarousel -->
```

According to markup this should work but it doesn't, the arrow by default if there is no more slide than one should be disabled but it is clickable.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are creating <div> only for numb=1 and creating <a> only for numb!=1. But posting your output markup will help :)

Comment: I have pasted the output, it doesnt seem to work but according to markup it should work and there should be four items only three are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i came out with answer for my own question, even though all the above answers gave me many ideas. Thank you all

```
function renderAds(){
    $query = queryAds();
    $query_exe = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_exe) == 0){
        echo '<img src="images/sampleAd.jpg" >';
    }else{
        $numb =1;
        $flag =1;
        echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
        while($fetched_data = mysql_fetch_array($query_exe)){
            if($numb == 1){
                if($flag == 1){
                    echo '<div class="active item">';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="item">';
                }
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://'.$fetched_data['url'].'" class="pull-left marginTop" ><img src="'.$fetched_data['image_url'].'"></a>';
            }elseif($numb == 4){
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://'.$fetched_data['url'].'"  class="pull-left marginLast" ><img src="'.$fetched_data['image_url'].'"></a>';
                $numb = 0;
                echo '</div>';
            }else{
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://'.$fetched_data['url'].'" class="pull-left marginTop" ><img src="'.$fetched_data['image_url'].'"></a>';
            }

            $numb++;
            $flag++;
        }

        if($numb > 1 && $numb < 4 ){
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }elseif($numb == 1){
            echo '</div>';
        }elseif($numb == 4){
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>';
        echo '<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the reason for the check "elseif($numb == 4)" is this something specific to your application or it is especially for the twitter carousel?

Answer (score 5):

Have you MySQL query return just an array. That way, your query's reusable (could be then made into a function) and you can render the data however you see fit.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

$rows = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
?>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<?php $item_class = ($i == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
      <a href="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" />
      </a>
    </div>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll obviously need to change the database query, as well as the values then used in the `foreach` loop. I've also used the `mysqli` functions, as the `mysql` functions are now deprecated in favour of MySQLi (MySQL improved).

Comment: I upvote here because, working or not, that's the general way it should be coded.

Comment: @monk Have you changed the variables to reflect your script's, as instructed? Or did you just copy-and-paste?

Comment: i did changed it, but no luck so far.. by the way i like your programming style very much

Comment: what should be the second argument for mysqli_query()

Comment: @monk I've updated the snippet. I think there was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

<?php 
// Twitter Bootstrap Carousel.
$caseStudies = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => 12,
  'post_type'   => 'case-study',
  'meta_key'    => 'show_case_study_home',
  'meta_value'  => 'yes',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
));

$open = 0;
$close = 1;
$active = 0;
$didClose = false;
foreach($caseStudies as $caseStudy){

  $image  = get_field('image_home', $caseStudy->ID);
  $header = get_field('header_home', $caseStudy->ID);
  $intro  = get_field('intro_home', $caseStudy->ID);

  $activeCss = "";

    if(($open)%4 == 0) {
      if ($active == 0) $activeCss = " active";
     echo '<div class="item'. $activeCss .'"><ul class="thumbnails">';
    }
?>

<li class="span3">
  <div class="case-study">
  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($caseStudy->ID); ?>" class="btn-more read-hover">Read More</a>
  <h4><?php echo $header; ?></h4>
  <p><?php echo $intro; ?></p>
  </div>
</li>

<?
    if(($close)%4 == 0) {
     echo "<ul></div>";
     $didClose = true; // Maybe the carousel has less than 4 items ...
    }

  $open++;
  $close++;
  $active++;
}
if($didClose == false) echo "</div></div>"; // If has less than 4 items in the carousel close the tags.
?>

</div><!--/.caroussel-inner -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php $slider = $guest->getAllData("slider"); ?>
            <?php foreach( $slider as $slide) : ?>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?=$slide['id']; ?>" class=""></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php foreach($slider as $slide) : ?>
                <div class="item ">
                    <img src="images/slider/<?=$slide['img']; ?>" alt="Los Angeles">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and add JS code:

```
$('.carousel-indicators>li:first-child').addClass('active');
$('.carousel-inner>div:first-child').addClass('active');
```