# how i use bootstrap slider in open cart

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

Is there anyone who try out bootstrap slide with opencart slideshow module?

Here is my code i am trying but getting all active classes. Someone can help me plz.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner slideshow <?php echo $module; ?>">
<div class="item active">

    <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can we have the html version? run it in your browser first then view page source. copy paste the div of `id="carousel-example-generic"` and its contents here.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually i need first div active for example,


<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

Answer (score 1):

UPD: loop must be like this

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>">
<?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
<?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
<div class="item"><a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"><span class="bootstrap_left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="bootstrap_right"></span></a>

</div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.item:first-child').addClass('active');
$('.carousel').carousel();
});
--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you refer or check the html version outputted of your code. If simillar
to what should bootstrap carousel setup should be?

Please do refer with it . [BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Else refer to this fiddle [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/juddlyon/Q2TYv/10/)

Carousel Script

```
// invoke the carousel
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 3000
});

/* SLIDE ON CLICK */ 

$('.carousel-linked-nav > li > a').click(function() {

    // grab href, remove pound sign, convert to number
    var item = Number($(this).attr('href').substring(1));

    // slide to number -1 (account for zero indexing)
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(item - 1);

    // remove current active class
    $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

    // add active class to just clicked on item
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    // don't follow the link
    return false;
});

/* AUTOPLAY NAV HIGHLIGHT */

// bind 'slid' function
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {

    // remove active class
    $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

    // get index of currently active item
    var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();

    // select currently active item and add active class
    $('.carousel-linked-nav li:eq(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: I know but i need first div active only. You also can see in bootstrap docs.

Comment: @user3263368 then you may post your carousel script as well please.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your 3rd line you have
`<div class="item active">` .

You need to include this inside the loop of your php.
Then create a condition that if it is the first item, set its class as `item active` and then in your else statement just `item`.

Try work it out with this example code.

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<?php $item_class = ($i == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
      <a href="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" />
      </a>
    </div>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please can you give me an example?

Comment: you can also view [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314800/twiiter-bootstrap-carousel-making-dynamic-with-php)

Comment: Thank you @adrian.
Here is working code so far but all div(s) comes again name as 'item' when i navigate it with **right carousel-control**.
`<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($banners as $banner): ?>
<?php $item_class = ($i == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
<div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
<a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
</div>
<?php $i++; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: But when you load it first does it appears to be ok?

Comment: yes everything working fine. but when i navigate it with right side control it appears nothing cause all classes back to "item" :(

Comment: It appears to be a different problem now. If the code above solves the issue then you can accept my answer and just ask another question regarding this new issue and we'll try to help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Manchary had the right idea. I have tested this, and run it in my Opencart.

Here's the full code to add to:
catalog/view/theme/*yourtheme*/template/module/carousel.tpl

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($banners as $banner) {
    echo "<li data-target=\"#myCarousel\" data-slide-to=\"".$i."\" class=\"indicator\"></li>\n";
    $i++;
}
?>
</ol>
<!-- slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
<?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
<div class="item"><a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#myCarousel ol.carousel-indicators li:first').addClass('active');
       $('#myCarousel .item:first').addClass('active');
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
    });
});
//]]> 
</script>
```

Note* If jQuery document ready is causing grief, you can try

```
window.onload = function() {
    // code here
}
```

Hope this helps someone.